# Writing to multiple remote terminals over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Let's say I am SSH'ing to multiple remote machines. I'd like to send commands to all the machines through one interface. I was thinking of opening a named pipe whose output would be piped to each machine I SSH into. That way if I `echo "ls -l" > namedpipe`, then the command would run on each machine. I tried this, but it didn't work. Any suggestions on how can I have one terminal from which I could interact with all the remote machines?

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is the way to go. There are lots of examples on SO and elsewhere, also using named pipes when needed. Other tools are mentioned and compared in the parallel manpage.

As to your example, what you want can be done as simply as

```
parallel ssh {} "ls -l" ::: user1@machine1 user2@machine2 ...
```

Some linux distributions come with a configuration file (usually `/etc/parallel/config` ) where the option `--tollef` is set by default. If this is your case and you don’t want to change, you must use `--` instead of `:::` in the first example above, or, alternatively, use the `--gnu` option to override `--tollef`.

Equivalently, if you create a file called `remotelist` containing

```
user1@machine1
user2@machine2
```

you can issue:

```
parallel -a remotelist ssh {} "ls -l"
```

or, as noted by a comment below,

```
parallel --nonall --slf remotelist ls -l
```

the `--slf` option (short for `--sshloginfile`) allows stuffing more information in the `remotelist` file: comments, number of processors to use on each remote host, and the like.

You might also consider the `--tag` option, which prepends each output line with the name of the host it originates from.

Comment: Use `--slf remotelist --nonall` and avoid quoting.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools available which could help you do that. Some of them it's worth checking at are:

[pssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh)
[Ansible Ad-Hoc module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_adhoc.html)

They both work over SSH.

If you still want to use a custom script with a SSH client, you could do something like:

```
while read i
do
    ssh user@$i <command to execute> <arg>
done < server.list
```

Comment: The useless use of `more` is a tough laugh/cry test.